# How do I create multiple records fieldsets for contacts?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, multi-record

I think this is a simple question, only i can't work out the answer!
How do I create multiple record fieldsets? Your help is much appreciated,

Cheers,

Kate

Answer (score 2):

When you create the custom field group, you select Contact, and then click anywhere and you should see a field pop in to view re 'multiple

See [image: screenshot]

And once you have added the Fields too, then you should see something like [image: this] on a contact record. (Grabbed before demo gets flushed)

Comment: Thanks. I'd got as far as selecting the the multiple records option, only once I've done that I'm not sure how to create multiple records within one field set. Specifically, it's the medications section of a health form. I want people to be able to answer what medication they're on, what it's for, how much they have, how often they have it and what times they have it. Is this the sort of information that I could record here or do I need to find a different way?! Mcuh appreciated!

Comment: so after making the Custom Field Set, you then need to make the actual field, eg Medication, which might be a text or more likely a Note field. And that should mean people can add a Medication, then click and add another one.

Comment: i made a field here - http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fcustom%2Fgroup%2Ffield&reset=1&new=1&gid=4&action=browse  and you can see outcome on this contact http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview&reset=1&cid=132&key=8a7a79dbfcaf044f619f2b8a128f841e_5737&context=advanced